# Formulario no muestra informacion en los input django

Tags: django, input

Estoy creando un pequeño crud en django para productos y proveedores pero  cuando quiero editar un producto no me muestra la informacion en los input.

**Views.py**

Enla vista recivo el id del producto a modificar y ese producto se lo paso a mi template:

```
def modificarProducto(request,id_prod):
    producto=Producto.objects.get(id=id_prod)
    return render(request,'formularios/modificar-producto.html',{
        'title':'Modificar Productos',
        'producto':producto
    })
```

**models.py**

Aqui el modelo del producto:

```
class Producto(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Nombre")
    cantidad=models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Cantidad")
    caducidad=models.DateField(verbose_name="Caducidad")
    precio_venta=models.FloatField(verbose_name="Precio venta")
    precio_compra=models.FloatField(verbose_name="Precio compra")
    proveedor=models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,verbose_name="Proveedor",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**modificar-producto.html**

En la template tengo un formulario y quiero que en cada input muestre su valor correspondiente pero solo me muestra los dos primeros

```
<form class="formulario" method="post"  action="{% url 'actualizar_producto' id_prod=producto.id%}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" value="{{producto.nombre}}"/>

    <label for="cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
    <input type="number" name="cantidad" value="{{producto.cantidad}}" />

    <label for="caducidad">Fecha de caducidad:</label>
    <input type="date" name="caducidad" value="{{producto.caducidad.value}}"/>

    <label for="precio_venta">Precio venta:</label>
    <input type="number" name="precio_venta" value="{{producto.precio_venta}}"/>

    <label for="precio_compra">Precio compra:</label>
    <input type="number" name="precio_compra" value="{{producto.precio_compra}}"/>
   
     <label class="required" for="proveedor">Proveedor:</label>
                          
        <select name="proveedor">
        <option value="{{producto.proveedor}}">{{prov.nombre}}</option>
        {% for prov in proveedores%}
            <option value="{{ prov.0}}">{{prov.1}}</option>

        {%endfor%}
        

    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Guardar"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en la vista. Debes declarar una instancia del producto a editar en tu data. Mira mi ejemplo:

```
def editProductPage(request, id):
    producto = Producto.objects.get(id=id)
    data = {
        'form': ProductoForm(instance=producto), 'producto':producto
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = ProductoForm(data=request.POST, instance=producto)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            formulario.save()
            return redirect(to='algun_template')
        data['form']=ProductoForm(instance=Producto.objects.get(id=id))
    return render(request,'admin/edit-product.html', data)
```

Luego, en el template, debes utilizar el form como static. Mira mi ejemplo de mi html:

```
<form class="container py-3 " action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h6><strong>Nombre Producto</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{form.name}}
        </div>
        <h6><strong>Precio</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{form.price}}
        </div>
        <h6><strong>Despacho Disponible</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{form.despacho}}
        </div>
        <h6><strong>Stock</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{form.stock}}
        </div>
        <h6><strong>Stock Crítico</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{form.critic_stock}}
        </div>
        <h6><strong>Imagen</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i></span>
            </div>
            <p>
            {{form.image}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <h6><strong>Proveedor</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{form.proveedor}}
        </div>
        <h6><strong>Familia de Producto</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-users"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{form.familia}}
        </div>
        <h6><strong>Tipo de Producto</strong></h6>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i></span>
            </div>
            {{form.tipo_producto}}
        </div>
        <div class="py-4">
            <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" value="Guardar y Publicar">
        </div>  
    </form>
```

Comment: Ojo en la data debes llamar al formulario que declaraste en tu archivo forms.py. No funcionará correctamente si usas el producto como instancia.